# Python version issue while configuring zbar

Tags: python, zbar

I am building zbar package on Linux but at configure stage, I'm stuck with the following error:

```
checking for a Python interpreter with version >= 2.3.5... none
configure: error: no suitable Python interpreter found
```

The strange this is that if i run `python --version` it returns 2.6.6. The python version is already satisfied. How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of linux are you running? I just installed zbar on ubuntu 12.10 with apt-get; `sudo apt-get install python-zbar`. The pypi-package for zbar is broken and I didn't even dare to touch the tarball. `python-zbar` works seamlessly although the docs for python specifically suck.

Comment: Install your distro's `python-devel` package.

Comment: @msvalkon: I'm on Angstrom with version3.7.0-rc4. In the distribution, I couldn't find the zbar directly.

Comment: @Shah ah well then you're on your own, as I said, I did not dare to attempt the installation from the tarball. Have you tried `pip` or `easy_install`?

Comment: @msvalkon: I can go without python, I think..but I really would like to install the zbar in quick way and less dependency issue, how do I do it if i wanna install zbar via `pip` or `easy_install`?

Comment: @Shah [pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) and [setuptools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools)